# Integrating a program into ROS

Tags: ros, build-package, 3rd-party-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm interested in integrating a program (ChatScript) into ROS. It's written in C++, platform independent, receives user input and generates output, can run as a local or a server. Run as a standalone, it runs in the terminal, one types in text, the program parses this text, selects the appropriate response and outputs that text to the terminal as text then waits for the next input.

With my limited but growing understanding of ROS, I should think it would just be a matter of generating a package that runs ChatScript (as written)as a node with a subscriber that listens for input then publishes the generated response. Is it really that simple?

Are there tutorials out there that would help me learn how to do this? I've been through the basic and intermediate tutorials and feel I'm right on the edge of knowing but not quite there.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157936/integrating-a-program-into-ros/) by [richkappler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2694/richkappler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2014-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should be it - http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage
If its a single node then you don't need to write any publisher/subscriber.  Just go through the ROS Tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [adreno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4576/adreno/) with karma: 253 on 2014-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fromandto](https://answers.ros.org/users/20325/fromandto/) on 2014-11-24**:
Hi adreno , it seems that when using the '<build_depend>' and '<run_depend>' tags can only access ros-built in libraries. How could I use a pre-compiled .a and .so in a ros node ? (I don't have the source code, it's a camera driver) THX !